# Android target in Cordova Requirements

Tags: android, cordova

I recently installed Cordova onto my laptop. I have installed all the requirements, like Java, Android SDK, etc. But I'm getting this error:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin\gradle
Error: Some of requirements check failed
```

I opened the SDK manager on Android Studio, and installed the SDKs for Android versions 23 to 26. But the it still gives the same error. Any fixes?

Comment: What target do you have in your code ? I mean in myApp/platforms/android/project.properties myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/project.properties and AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: It shows "target=android-25 in project.properties. AndroidManifest shows android:minSdkVersion="14"

Comment: How about targetSDKVersion in AndroidManifest.xml and can you paste project.properties `myApp/platforms/android/project.properties myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/project.properties` sorry I can't guess the things

Comment: myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/project.properties:

    # Project target.
    target=android-25
    apk-configurations=
    renderscript.opt.level=O0
    android.library=true

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml:

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.apache.cordova" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
</manifest>

Comment: set targetSDKVersion to 25 in `AndroidManifest.xml`